# Как считать граф в список смежности?

Tags: графы

Повсюду есть множество различных алгоритмов о графах. Но как представить граф в виде списка смежности? На многих сайтах написано сделать это так

```
vector<vector<int>>g;
cin>>v>>u;
g[v].push_back(u);
```

Но мой компилятор ругается и выдаёт исключение стандартного контейнера вектор _DEBUG_ERROR("vector subscript out of range")
В чём моя ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается всё просто. Не попадайте в такие ловушки. На всех сайтах напиано просто g. а нужно в круглых скобках после g указать размер.